# using mysqli::prepare within an already established connection using prepare?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Quick question. Whilst using the `prepare` method in mysqli. It is possible/a good idea; to use it twice within the same mysqli connection? Example:

OOP layered

```
public function getStuff(){
    $posts=array();
    $query = $this->DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE stuff =?');
    $query->bind_param('s','param');
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($ID,$col1,$col2,$etc);
    while($query->fetch()){
        $posts[]=array('ID'=>$ID,'col1'=>$col1,'extras'=>$this->getExtras($ID));
    }
    $query->close();
    return $posts;
}
private function getExtra($postID){
    $extras=array();
    $query = $this->DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM anotherTable WHERE moreStuff =?');
    $query->bind_param('s',$postID);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($ID,$col1,$col2,$etc);
    while($query->fetch()){
        $extras[]=array('ID'=>$ID,'col1'=>$col1,'etc'=>$etc);
    }
    $query->close();
    return $extras;
}
```

Right my possible error is that I've used the same variable and the same database connection. I'm not 100% sure this will work as I've called $this->DBH whilst it is already being used in the parent function. Is there a better method to what I'm trying to achieve or is there a better structure I can use. Or should I just give up and use a separate variable? lol

Hopeful outcome:

```
$posts=array('ID'=>'column ID number','col1'=>'column1 data', 'extras'=>array('ID'=>'second table\'s ID number','col1'=>'second tables data','etc'=>'etc etc etc'));
```

Comment: Did you try to run the code? Do you get the expected result and/or any error? However you could add the extra information by looping over the $posts array afterwards.

Comment: Well the `getstuff()` function returned correctly (without the second function). I'm just wondering if there are complications with the way I've structured the two queries together? Because $this->DBH is already being queried and in my second function `getExtra()` I'm querying the same connection again. Not sure whether this may cause problems?

Comment: I don't think it causes problems, but maybe I'm wrong. Just give it a try. If it does, we'll fix it -- or just add the extra information by looping over the $posts array afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example above, the variables which matter are `$query`.  Each of those is local to its own method, and so the variables themselves will not collide. The MySQLi connection `$this->DBH` is capable of handling multiple open statements at once *if circumstances are right*.

The place where you need to use caution is with their execution order.  If you prepare and execute a statement but do not fetch all rows from it, you may not be able to `prepare()` the next one until all rows have been fetched unless you first close it with [`mysqli_stmt::close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php) to deallocate the open statement handle.

For example:

```
// Prepares successfully:
$s1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM t1");
// Also prepares successfully (previous one not executed)
$s2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM t2");

// Then consider:
$s1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM t1");
$s1->bind_result($id, $name);
$s1->execute();
// And attempt to prepare another
$s2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM t2");
// Fails because $s1 has rows waiting to be fetched.
echo $m->error;
// "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"
```

#### Edit: misread your example...

Looking at your example above, you are indeed calling `getExtras()` *while* you are fetching from the `getStuff()` statement. You may run into the issue described above.  Your two operations in this case may be able to be handled with a single `JOIN` instead, from which you fetch in only one loop to populate all your variables and build your output array as you want it.  Depending on your need, this should either be an `INNER JOIN` if a related row is expected to exist in the `othertable`, or a `LEFT JOIN` if the related `othertable` may or may not have a row that matches the given ID.

```
SELECT 
  maintable.id, 
  maintable.col1,
  othertable.col2,
  othertable.col3
FROM
  maintable
  JOIN othertable ON maintable.id = othertable.id
```

Comment: Ahh ha! thank you I think that's my problem :) I had a feeling something would conflict so I thought I'd better ask. As for `JOIN` I've never seen that before and that could quiet possibly be my answer. It would also enable me to use only the one function rather than the two that I've provided. I've also noticed you've mentioned a `PDO` layer. I was using mysqli. Would this make a difference to the functionality?

Comment: @Beneto Sorry that was supposed to be MySQLi, not PDO.  Spend some time learning about SQL joins, as they are crucial knowledge and when used correctly can impart enormous speed gains over doing multiple queries in a loop

Comment: I usually recommend [this visual explanation of SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) written by one of Stack Overflow's two founders...

Comment: @MichealBrekowski No problem :) I had a feeling you meant mySQLi lol that's cool I'll check that out :) Thanks again for your help :) I really should look more into SQL queries as like you said would limit the amount of queries I make.

Comment: Didn't know about it. Great answer! +1